# Euler #2 in C++

Tags: c++

So, I'm new to C++ and I've decided to do some Euler problems... The thing is, I can't seem to get past problem 2. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the logic as far as I can tell, so maybe it's a programming problem. The build runs, but gives me a wrong answer of 19,544,084.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 0;
int total = 0;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

while (a <= 4000000 || b <= 4000000 || c <= 4000000) {
    c = a + b;
        if (c % 2 == 0) {
            total += c;
        }
    a = c + b;
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            total += a;
        }
    b = a + c;
        if (b % 2 == 0) {
            total += b;
        }
}
total += 2; // Didn't start with 2 in Fibonacci, so added it at end.
cout << total;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo there. The language you are learning is C++.

Comment: An `int` variable cannot be bigger than 32,767 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: @clyfe: you're wrong for any reasonably modern, non-embedded machine. `int` is pretty much always at least 32-bits these days.

Comment: @clyfe, what architecture are you working on? Pretty sure most computers made in the last 20 years are rocking at least 32-bit registers now, and compilers default to `sizeof(int) == 4`

Comment: Am I missing something, or do you mean a short, @clyfe?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, school memories kicked in!

Comment: At compile time, `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are macros for the lower and upper limit of `int`, if you have included the header file `<limits.h>` (C) or `<climits>` (C++). `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are *guaranteed to be at least* -32768..32767, which is a 16 bit `int`. But on a 32-bit machine, you will have a 32-bit `int`, on a 36-bit machine, a 36-bit `int`, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. It is possible that when you enter your loop a, b, and c are all less than 4 million, but the sum of two numbers less than 4 million doesn't have to be less than 4 million too. Before you add you number to total, you also need to check that the value is less than 4 million.

`if (c < 4000000 && c % 2 == 0)`

Do the same for a and b.

Comment: This is the proper answer. I changed it and got the right answer immediately. Thank you.